# Spring Security Role Hierarchy not working with Thymeleaf sec:authorize

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring Security 3.2.5.RELEASE with ThymeLeaf 2.1.4.RELEASE. I've defined Role Hierarchy in my security context. In my view layer I'm using `sec:authorize` attribute to define menu items. I expect to see all menu items under the top level role but I only see the menus defined under that role. How can I fix this problem so that I see all menus under the top level?

Any pointers would be really appreciated. Thanks.

```
<beans:bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleHierarchyVoter">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="roleHierarchy"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="roleHierarchy" class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
    <beans:property name="hierarchy">
        <beans:value>
            ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR > ROLE_MANAGER > ROLE_CONTENT_ADMINISTRATOR
        </beans:value>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

And in my view page I'm using `sec:authorize` attribute like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<body th:fragment="admin-menu" sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')">
<li>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> <span class="nav-label">Users</span> </a>
</li>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

In order to get the role hierarchy worked in thymeleaf templates as well as in the common security (annotation) config, you need only 2 things:

1. Make the bean:

   ```
   @Bean
   public RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy() {
   RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
   String hierarchy =
           "ADMIN_GLOBAL_MANAGEMENT > ADMIN_COMMON " +
           "ADMIN_GLOBAL_MANAGEMENT > ADMIN_USER_MANAGEMENT " +
           "ADMIN_GLOBAL_MANAGEMENT > ADMIN_PAYMENT_MANAGEMENT " +
           "ADMIN_GLOBAL_MANAGEMENT > ADMIN_MESSAGE_MANAGEMENT";
    roleHierarchy.setHierarchy(hierarchy);
    return roleHierarchy;
   }
   ```
2. Extend **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** and override a method:

   ```
   @EnableWebSecurity
   public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   ...

   @Override
   public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
     DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new 
       DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
     expressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy());
     web.expressionHandler(expressionHandler);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a similar hierarchy. The answer is explained here [Spring Security Role Hierarchy issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860705/spring-security-role-hierarchy-issues). This works for me:

```
<sec:http> ...
    <sec:expression-handler ref="defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler" />
...
```

```
<beans:bean id="roleHierarchy" class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
    <beans:property name="hierarchy">
        <beans:value>
            ROLE_SYSTEMADMIN > ROLE_JOURNALADMIN
            ROLE_JOURNALADMIN > ROLE_ESUBS
            ROLE_ESUBS > ROLE_STAFF
        </beans:value>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="methodSecurityExpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <beans:property name = "roleHierarchy" ref="roleHierarchy"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler">
      <beans:property name="roleHierarchy" ref="roleHierarchy"/>
</beans:bean>


 <beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleHierarchyVoter">
                <beans:constructor-arg ref="roleHierarchy" />
            </beans:bean>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter">
                <beans:property name="expressionHandler" ref="defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler"/>
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. What version of Spring, Spring Security and ThymeLeaf did you use?

Answer (score 0):

As a first instance I tried to update my dependencies, but with no luck.

Shortly what my application have:
- web security configuration using role hierarchy
- enabled global method security  `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)`

All parts where working properly except Thymeleaf expression
`sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"` did not take hierarchy into account.

Then I tried to debug, and I found out that when expression was evaluated, there were 2 `DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler`:
- 1 with key `webSecurityExpressionHandler`
- 1 with key `defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler` (bean defined by me with hierarchy.

So I had 2 options:
- either intercept `webSecurityExpressionHandler` an d sets role hierarchy on it; or
- rename my bean definition from `defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler` to `webSecurityExpressionHandler`.

As I don't need to have to security expression handler, I picked option number 2.

Note:
In case you want to see if you don't have any other beans, see
`org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.auth.AuthUtils@243` (Line 243, method getExpressinHandler)

This might be the case in older version (inlcuding Thymeleaf 2.x.x)